# WordPress database error: [Table 'wp_users' already exists]

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, custom-wordpress-pages

I cant accsess the wordpress website that I've already submitted on my localhost

Although I have already submitted the website I cant access it with "http://localhost/saargolpurmohamad.ir" and it redirects me to the installation page, when I fill it out I get "WordPress database error: [Table 'wp_users' already exists]".
How can I accsess my website again?

Comment: 1. Do you have access to change wp-config.php file & check the database name?

Answer (score 0):

It simple delete all tables from database and process again. dont forgot to check wp-config.php file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).